# What is the missing number, can anyone solve this? My original puzzle

Tags: pattern

What is the missing number that should be put in place of the question mark?

3,3=17

2,5=28

3,4=24

4,5=40

5,8=88

6,11=156

6,9=?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the answer?

> 116

The pattern/reasoning is

> (a^2 + b^2) -1 = answer

Comment: No brackets needed.

Comment: Good point. Clearly it's been a while since I worked on orders of operations. Guess it's just a little window into how I was thinking about the answer.

Answer (score 7):

If the three numbers in each "equation" are $a$, $b$, $c$ then one possible solution is

> $Min(a, 5)^2 + b^2 - 1 = c$, giving the answer $c = 105$ for the last.

**Edit**

For good measure, the corrected version of the puzzle has the simpler solution

> $a^2 + b^2 - 1 = c$, giving the answer $c = 116$ for the last.

Comment: It doesnt work for 6,11 but fits all others. Maybe there was a typo?

Comment: It works.  But I wonder if "6,11 = 146" was meant to be "6,11 = 156" which would remove the need for the whole "Min" part of it which seems a bit arbitrary?

Comment: yes you were right there was an error in the puzzle